# Set QWORD with a constant value in IDA Pro

Tags: ida, debugging, dll

At **line #3** of a function, I have a QWORD at address 7FE875F3FE0 which resolves to a value of **85857490416** for which the function returns true. If not, the value is set to 0.

I would like to know how can I modify this QWORD to the said sequence of digits so that the function returns true. I have tried assembling this LoC, but it kills the function due to the non-match of the byte padding.

**Code Cave** is an option? If so, can somebody help me? Else a MOV statement?

Just started recently with RE and IDA Pro.

**Code Segment**

```
push    rbx
sub     rsp, 20h
mov     rax, cs:qword_7FE875F3FE0
mov     rbx, rcx
test    rax, rax
jnz     short loc_7FE8728D09D

loc_7FE8728D09D:
mov     [rcx], rax
xor     eax, eax
add     rsp, 20h
pop     rbx
retn
```

**.data** representation of the QWORD

```
.data:000007FE875F3FE0 qword_7FE875F3FE0 dq ? 
.data:000007FE875F3FE0                                         
.data:000007FE875F3FE8 db    ? ;
.data:000007FE875F3FE9 db    ? ;
.data:000007FE875F3FEA db    ? ;
.data:000007FE875F3FEB db    ? ;
```

Comment: If your goal is to just have the function return `true`, why not just patch the function directly to always return `true` so that it never even looks at the value at `qword_7FE875F3FE0`?

Comment: The reason is because subsequent functions after this block looks for this particular value inside the `[rcx]` register. Performing what you suggest would then always result a value 0 to `[rcx]`. Future function calls depend on the validity of this register.

Comment: How do you arrive at 85857490416 from your code example? The code you posted will return 0, which is false, not true, if the value at qword_7FE875F3FE0 is anything but zero.

Comment: Because if I hover over `qword_7FE875F3FE0` on LIne #3, I see this value which changes to `15483925093871637495` in the second segment move into `[rcx]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would likely be to patch the first block of the function to be the following:

```
push    rbx
sub     rsp, 20h
mov     rax, 85857490416
mov     rbx, rcx
```

Though `mov rax, 85857490416` will consume extra bytes, you can remove `test rax, rax` and `jnz short loc_7FE8728D09D` to compensate.

And if it still doesn't fit, then yes, a code-cave would likely be the next option.

Comment: What happens to the second half of the function that comes under the purview of `loc_7FE8728D09D`? Could you also point me to the code-cave alternative/sources as I would like to learn the same with this question.

Comment: As long as you only patch the first block, it should be fine.

Comment: So the code doesn't fit in. The program crashes on `sub rsp, 20h` I believe that a code-cave approach is necessary. Would it be possible for you to append a code-cave alternative to this query? Just the code part and not the basic how-to.

Comment: If the program crashes on `sub rsp, 20h` then something is very very wrong...

Comment: @Jason Geffner: Why consumes mov rax, 85857490416 more bytes than the (to be replaced) mov     rax, cs:qword_7FE875F3FE0 ? Doesn't it consume one byte less to give space for a NOP? The bytecode should give evidence.