# Code-Cave Assembly Patching Issue in x64_dbg

Tags: ida, disassembly, x86-64, patching, machine-code

I'm trying a code-cave approach to [this](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/9366/set-qword-with-a-constant-value-in-ida-pro) query that was asked about on this forum earlier.

I'm using **x64_dbg** to perform this task. My issue here is that after I have written the extra lines of assembly within the code-cave, using `Right-Click > Patches` does not apply them.

Does **x64_dbg** require an additional add-on to perform this kind of patching?
However, the code changes inside the address space of the function patches just fine.

Assembly code (Code-Cave)

[image]

Failed dialog box

[image]

Comment: Where did you place the code cave? If you put it at the end of the other code, it might be beyond the end of the segment, which would explain why windbg can't write it back.

Comment: I scrolled all the way to the bottom of the window and wrote it there.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work me. I tried patching the virtual sizes of all the section headers and it didn't make any difference...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[x64_dbg](http://x64dbg.com/) uses [TitanEngine](http://reversinglabs.com/open-source/titanengine.html)'s `ConvertVAtoFileOffsetEx()` function to apply the patches. That function validates that the virtual addresses of the bytes to be patched are within a section's memory space at run-time (based on the section's virtual address and the section's virtual size). Since the bytes you're patching are after the end of the section's virtual size, `ConvertVAtoFileOffsetEx()` returns `0` and the patches are never applied.

As a workaround, I'd recommend patching the virtual size of the section to which you're appending those new bytes. Whatever the current virtual size is, make it `14` bytes bigger in the PE section's header.

You can use a tool like [Explorer Suite](http://www.ntcore.com/exsuite.php) to make this change by navigating to the file's *Section Headers* and increasing the value in the target section's *Virtual Size* field:

[image: Explorer Suite]

Comment: Could you kindly also reference a few links on a **how-to** for patching the virtual size of the section header in your answer ?

Comment: I've updated my answer above with a link and instructions.